# Leetcode 695 javascript recursion not working as expected

Tags: javascript, recursion

My solution to leetcode's MaxAreaOfAnIsland isn't working as I expect it to, and it has me wondering about javascript recursion.

In the code below, I'm creating an array to track whether or not an element from the grid array has already been visited via recursive action.  However, if you run the code and look at the many console.log()'s, the final answer for the size of the largest island is incorrect.

WIERDEST of all, the shadowGrid array transforms incorrectly during the course of the program execution, and in doing so it somehow becomes a repeated copy of the same array [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0].

I have been staring at leetcode for days now, so maybe I'm fried and missing something, but I think it has something to do with the line
`return 1 +  countLand(idR-1, idC) + countLand(idR+1, idC) + countLand(idR, idC-1) + countLand(idR, idC+1);`

If someone can explain to me what's happening here, especially if it's a recursion quirk, I'll become a better programmer and appreciate the help!  Thanks.

```
function maxAreaOfIsland(grid){
    var shadowGrid = Array(grid.length).fill(Array(grid[0].length).fill(0)),//shadow the area of grid, filled with 0's
        islandSize = 0;
    console.log(shadowGrid);

    function countLand(idR, idC){
        console.log(`idR and idC in recursion: irR- ${idR} : idC- ${idC}`);
        
        if(idR < 0 || idR >= grid.length || idC < 0 || idC >= grid[0].length || shadowGrid[idR][idC] == 1 || grid[idR][idC] == 0 ){
            return 0;
        }
        
        console.log(`idR and idC in recursion: irR- ${idR} : idC- ${idC}`);
        shadowGrid[idR][idC] = 1;
        return 1 +  countLand(idR-1, idC) + countLand(idR+1, idC) + countLand(idR, idC-1) + countLand(idR, idC+1);
    }

    for(let idR = 0; idR < grid.length; idR++){
        for(let idC = 0; idC < grid[0].length; idC++){
            console.log(`countLand: ${countLand(idR, idC)},  grid[idR][idC] = ${grid[idR][idC]},  islandSize : ${islandSize}`);
            islandSize = Math.max(countLand(idR, idC), islandSize);
            console.log(`islandSize is as: ${islandSize}`);
        }
    }
    console.log(shadowGrid);
    return islandSize;
}

var grid = [[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
            [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
            [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]];
console.log(maxAreaOfIsland(grid));

/*shadowGrid at end of execution:
               [[0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
                [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
                [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
                [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
                [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
                [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
                [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
                [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]];
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you are filling the outer array with the same inner array reference. Regarding [`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), the documentation specifies:

> When fill gets passed an object, it will copy the reference and fill the array with references to that object.

Recall that in Javascript objects are passed by reference and because of this behavior of the `fill` method, it copies every reference to one position, so you're asking to put this same array in each position.

One workaround is to use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to put a distinct array into each position

```
var shadowGrid = Array(grid.length).fill(0).map(x => Array(grid[0].length).fill(0))
```

Comment: Oh, wow.  I had no idea about the reference being passed when I used the fill() method.  The shadowGrid is performing the way I had expected now, thanks!  That will definitely save me some trouble moving forward.  Any thoughts on why the recursive countLand() function is not incrementing the return value?  I keep getting a final 'islandSize' equal to whatever islandSize is being initialized to.

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix the problem with my recursion.  I changed the line: ```islandSize = Math.max(countLand(idR, idC), islandSize);``` and added enclosing parentheses around the countLand(idR, idC) call, making it ```islandSize = Math.max((countLand(idR, idC)), islandSize); ```.   That's something to keep in mind!